# Why do I get different results between Powershell and C#

Tags: c#, powershell, datetime, bit-shift

I have a method that converts a datetime to a DOS format

It was originally in C# but I have converted it to powershell.

The same input into both returns different results.
I'm struggling to see why.

Powershell method

```
Function ConvertTo-DOSDate {
    Param(
        [DateTime]$dateTime

    )

    Process {
        Try {

            [int] $ret = (($dateTime.Year - 1980) -band 0x7F);
            $ret = ($ret -shl 4) + $dateTime.Month;
            $ret = ($ret -shl 5) + $dateTime.Day;
            $ret = ($ret -shl 5) + $dateTime.Hour;
            $ret = ($ret -shl 6) + $dateTime.Minute;
            $ret = ($ret -shl 5) + ($dateTime.Second / 2); # only 5 bits for second, so we only have a granularity of 2 sec.
            return  [uint32] $ret;

        }
        Catch {

            throw "Exception: $_"
        }
    }

}
```

C# Method

```
  public static uint DateTimeToDosTime(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            // DateTime must be Convertible to DosTime:
            //#Debug.Assert(ValidZipDate_YearMin <= dateTime.Year && dateTime.Year <= ValidZipDate_YearMax);

            int ret = ((dateTime.Year - 1980) & 0x7F);
            ret = (ret << 4) + dateTime.Month;
            ret = (ret << 5) + dateTime.Day;
            ret = (ret << 5) + dateTime.Hour;
            ret = (ret << 6) + dateTime.Minute;
            ret = (ret << 5) + (dateTime.Second / 2); // only 5 bits for second, so we only have a granularity of 2 sec.
            return (uint)ret;
        }
```

In a powershell console I run:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\temp\ClassLibrary1.dll"
$date = New-Object DateTime 2019, 08, 30, 20, 56, 43 
$powershellResult = ConvertTo-DOSDate -dateTime $date 
$CSharpResult = [TomLib.ZipHelper]::DateTimeToDosTime($date)

write-host "Input Date : $date"
Write-host "Powershell: $powershellResult"
write-host "C#: $CSharpResult"
```

Then the output

```
Input Date : 08/30/2019 20:56:43
Powershell: 1327408918
C#: 1327408917
```

Comment: I'd suspect a difference in rounding strategy; do you find that it's off by one half the time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-6 says:

> DIVISION AND ROUNDING
> When the quotient of a division operation is an integer, PowerShell rounds the value to the nearest integer. When the value is .5, it rounds to the nearest even integer.
>
> The following example shows the effect of rounding to the nearest even integer.

```
Expression  Result
[int]( 5 / 2 )  2
[int]( 7 / 2 )  4

Notice how 5/2 = 2.5 gets rounded to 2. But, 7/2 = 3.5 gets rounded to 4.
```

---

When C# does division in int space it just cuts the decimal parts:

```
5/2 -> 2, 
7/2 -> 3
```

In powershell your example time has a seconds component of 43, and `43/2` is hence rounded up to 22, the nearest even integer

In C# `43/2` is 21

This introduces an off by one error in your results, as in the C# form you're doing ret+21 and in the powershell form you're $ret+22

Comment: Thank you very much.

Any suggestions on how i can force powershell to perform like C#?

Comment: You could review the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863772/powershell-round-down-to-nearest-whole-number